# Search into JSON and get keys

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-web-services

I'm trying since a few day to get a result from a JSON here is my problem

I'm calling an AWS API which send me a complete JSON like this :

```
[
  {
    "ID": "12345",
  "key": value
  },
    {
    "ID": "23456",
  "key": value
  },
    {
    "ID": "34567",
  "key": value
  },
    {
    "ID": "45678",
  "key": value
  },
    {
    "ID": "56789",
  "key": value
  },
    {
    "ID": "67890",
  "key": value
  },
    {
    "ID": "76543",
  "key": value
  },
    {
    "ID": "987654",
  "key": value
  }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is : the user will enter an ID in a form, submit it and get a page with value depending on the JSON "keys"

The problem is my API doesn't have any endpoint which can get me only the specific ID datas, only my list of ID's inside this JSON (which is multiple k lines long) and get the value

Do you have any idea how I can solve this ?

Thanks in advance,

JB

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should not assume that people here are speaking every possible language. Please, post your question in English.

Comment: Please ask in English language only!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I translate it in English :)

Comment: Is it an array or object?

Comment: I got an object from the API, that I transform in JSON

Comment: yes but is the JSON an array of object, or key value (as a json should be) the way you're printing it, it's more an array of object

Comment: It's exactly what I posted, with more key/values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So use **`find`** method of an array. **`find`** method will returns only  one object it matched with.

```
const result = {};
const arr = [
       {
          "ID": "12345",
          "key": value
       }, 
       {
         "ID": "23456",
         "key": value
       },... ];

result = arr.find(item => item.ID === 'searchId');
```

Comment: I have the same error that .filter() : .find() is not a function.

Comment: Can you provide some more info regarding your data? As I am seeing you data is in array format like: [{},{}]. If it is so then it should work. It will be good if you attach image of your data from the console.

Comment: Yes, here is : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59453596/7998542

Comment: What is this.datas? Tell me the structure of this.datas? This is not possible this error can come if this.data is an array

Comment: Yes sorry, so I have a function that call my service, here is the function `getAllData() { this.httpClient.getAllData() .then(data => { this.datas = data; console.log(this.datas); this.value = '987654'; this.res = this.datas.find(item => item.POID === this.value); console.log(this.res); }); } `

Comment: Yes seems understandable. Just one more thing show us this.datas? You can create dummy data but it should be exact what you get from the back-end?

Comment: Ok, in the .then I get back this from the API : [{"POID": "12345","HUID": "136 600 533 730 630 000","UMinterne": "30052698","Livraison": "180535353","Quantit�": "5 400,00","UQ": "PC","Article": "1106210","Lot": "SDF3464567","ScanCustomdate": "01/07/2019","ScanLocation": "Paris","Datep�remption/DLC": "31/01/2020","Derni�remodificat.": "26/03/2018","Fournisseur": "COMPANY","Datefabrication": "27/04/2017","Num�roobjetinterne": "1300771","PackagedproductID": "CFO03857389","Internationaltradename": "PRODUCT","GlobalTradeItemNumer": "383493728284905","ShelfLifeValue": "1095"},...]

Comment: Exactly in this form. Then I work on it with parse and so on

Comment: Ok I find the solution, in fact the .find() was using the const arr but this const wasn't at the good format Array<>. Now it's ok, thanks guy !

Answer (score 0):

The datas are in an array excatly as I mantionned in the [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59453128/7998542) 
For security purpose I cannot share the exactly JSON with datas, so I rewrite it with some fake datas. 
Here is the console on the error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqt6o.png)